# Specific heat fit using Debye+Einstein model in matplotlib

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to find a fit to a specific heat data using gamma*T+m*Debye_model+(1-m)*Einstein model as given below.

Cel+ph(T ) = γ T + [αCDebye(T ) + (1 − α)CEinstein(T )]

where the Debye and Einstein models are given by eq. 3 and 4 in the attachment.

I have tried the following code in jupyter notebook following some examples on the web but i have no idea how can i combine these functions together to carry out the fit.

The data is linked https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0r2m3zwl8w77at/HC_ScPtBi.dat?dl=0
Column 1 is Temperature and Column 3 is Y data of interest.
Model is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/9452fq7eydajr5o/Debye.pdf?dl=0

Code is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/hk9b1t0agvt36zn/Untitled2.ipynb?dl=0

```
from matplotlib import pyplot 
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import quad

data=np.genfromtxt('HC_ScPtBi.dat', skip_header=1)
R=8.314
n=3
M=1
T=data[10:290,0]
c=data[10:290,2]
def plot_data():
    pyplot.scatter(T, c)
    pyplot.xlabel('$T [K]$')
    pyplot.ylabel('$C$')

plot_data()
def c_einstein(T, T_E):
    x = T_E / T
    return 3 *n*R*x**2 * np.exp(x) / (np.exp(x) - 1)**2

popt0, pcov0 = curve_fit(c_einstein, T, c, 250)
T_E = popt0[0]
delta_T_E = np.sqrt(pcov0[0, 0])
print(f"T_E = {T_E:.5} ± {delta_T_E:.3} K")
print(popt0)

plot_data()
#temps = np.linspace(10, T[-1], 100)
pyplot.plot(T, c_einstein(T, *popt0));

def integrand(y):
    return y**4 * np.exp(y) / (np.exp(y) - 1)**2

@np.vectorize
def c_debye(T, T_D):
    x = T / T_D
    return 9 *n*R*x**3 * quad(integrand, 0, 1/x)[0]

popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(c_debye, T, c, 150)
T_D = popt1[0]
delta_T_D = np.sqrt(pcov1[0, 0])
print(f"T_D = {T_D:.5} ± {delta_T_D:.3} K")
print(popt1)
plot_data()
pyplot.plot(T, c_einstein(T, *popt0), label='Einstein')
pyplot.plot(T, c_debye(T,  *popt1), label='Debye')
pyplot.legend();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it might be of any use, I obtained an excellent fit to a modified Weibull peak equation, with R-squared = 0.99999 and RMSE = 0.06878.

[image]

```
def Peak_WeibullPeak_Modified_model(x): # from zunzun.com
    a = 6.4654735487019195E+01
    b = 3.4517137038577323E+02
    c = -1.5940608784806631E+00
    d = 2.7331145870203617E+00

    return = a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * numpy.power(numpy.log(x/b) / c, d))
```

Comment: Wow, I am amazed with the fit, but It's not going to help my case. The functions I mentioned should also fit the data, just that I haven't figured out how to combine them. Hoping some geek to help me out on this. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the Einstein and Debye equations into a single function, which should look something like this:

```
def func(T, alpha,gamma,T_e,T_d):
   fn = lambda y: y**4 * np.exp(y) / (np.exp(y) - 1)**2
   einst = (1-alpha)*3*n*R*T_e**2/T**2 * np.exp(T_e/T) / (np.exp(T_e/T) - 1)**2
   debye_int = np.array([integrate.quad(fn, 0, T_d/t)[0] for t in T])
   debye = alpha*9*n*R*T**3/T_d**3*debye_int
   return einst+debye+gamma*T
```

You can then use that function in the curve fitting

```
coefs = curve_fit(func, T, c)[0]
plt.plot(T, func(T, *coefs))
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer.